# How do I create an App-like header with html/css?

Tags: iphone, css, cordova, header

I'm building an app with Phonegap/Cordova and Web standards, such as HTML and CSS. However, somewhere on the part of creating this, my skills aren't sufficient.

Ok, let's get this straight: I'm trying to create a navigation bar at the top of the screen. Very basic, even without buttons, just plain text with links.

Check-out this screenshot. As you might see or not.. The middle one isn't exactly placed in the middle. I've tried with div styles, span classes and tables seem the best option.. Yet still insufficient.

What's the best option to create such header?

[image]

p.s. No, of course there won't be a border in the table :D - Just for viewing. ^^

Comment: I personally wouldn't do it with a table. Are you talking about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xmJRM/)?

Comment: Visually, Yes that's exactly what I want to achieve! However, can you change the height of the blue rectangles to 10%, instead of pixel based? As I'm trying to create a page without multiple stylesheets,but still supporting all android phone screens; thus using % instead of px.

I've tried myself, but the rectangles disappear..
I've got an idea by now. trying out ;)

Edit: I'm able to change the height of each block to percentages, but the text verticaly aligned to the middle, with line-height set to percentages doesn't work (yet). Solution? :D

Comment: If you're trying to support multiple screen sizes then you might want to look into using a responsive framework like Bootstrap or Foundation. It'd be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: You can use jquery-mobile framework. In website main page there is try yourself section where you can generate sample UI by just drag and drop as you want in this question.  http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an example of something like this for a talk... here's a basic version with just a header and some scrollable content: http://jsbin.com/UWeQeli/1/edit

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wooohooo, that seems even better. Thanks, incredibly mate! 
Now only to have a screen slide in from left to right and I'm completely done. Thanks!

Comment: For your slide in: http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/03/hardware-accelerated-page-transitions-for-mobile-web-apps-phonegap-apps/